# how to save all record show in datagridview to the database

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

i have this code that will save only the top row of the datagridview,
can someone help me to modify this code so that it will save all the row in datagridview. im using vb 2010 and my database is ms access. thankyou in advance.

```
  Try
        Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection(conString)
        query = "Insert into tblreportlog(EmpID,empname,department,empdate,timeinaM,timeoutam,lateam,timeinpm,timeoutpm,latepm,thw) values ('" & dgvReport.Item(0, dgvReport.CurrentRow.Index).Value & "', '" & dgvReport.Item(1, dgvReport.CurrentRow.Index).Value & "', '" & dgvReport.Item(2, dgvReport.CurrentRow.Index).Value & "','" & dgvReport.Item(3, dgvReport.CurrentRow.Index).Value & "','" & dgvReport.Item(4, dgvReport.CurrentRow.Index).Value & "','" & dgvReport.Item(5, dgvReport.CurrentRow.Index).Value & "','" & dgvReport.Item(6, dgvReport.CurrentRow.Index).Value & "','" & dgvReport.Item(7, dgvReport.CurrentRow.Index).Value & "', '" & dgvReport.Item(8, dgvReport.CurrentRow.Index).Value & "','" & dgvReport.Item(9, dgvReport.CurrentRow.Index).Value & "','" & dgvReport.Item(10, dgvReport.CurrentRow.Index).Value & "')"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, cnn)
        cnn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cnn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ERROR: " & ErrorToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert!!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working from what is shown and best practices injected, you should be working from a data source such as a DataTable e.g. if when presented the DataGridView to the user there are no rows then create a new DataTable, set the DataTable as the DataSource of the DataGridView then when you are ready to save these rows in the DataGridView cast the DataSource of the DataGridView to a DataTable and use logic similar to the following

```
Dim dt As DataTable = CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Your connection string"}
        ' part field list done here
        Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With
            {
                .Connection = cn,
                .CommandText = "Insert into tblreportlog(EmpID,empname,department) values (@EmpID,@empname,@department)"
            }

            ' TODO - field names, field types
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(
                {
                    {New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@EmpID", .DbType = DbType.Int32}},
                    {New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@empname", .DbType = DbType.Int32}},
                    {New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@department", .DbType = DbType.String}}
                }
            )

            Dim Affected As Integer = 0

            cn.Open()

            Try
                For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    ' this should not be a auto-incrementing key
                    cmd.Parameters("@EmpID").Value = row.Field(Of Integer)("FieldName goes here")
                    cmd.Parameters("@empname").Value = row.Field(Of Integer)("FieldName goes here")
                    cmd.Parameters("@department").Value = row.Field(Of String)("FieldName goes here")

                    Affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
                    If Affected <> 1 Then
                        Console.WriteLine("Error message, insert failed")
                    End If
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
                '
                ' handle exception
                '
                ' for now
                MessageBox.Show("Failed with: " & ex.Message)
                ' decide to continue or not
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End If
```

On the other hand, if there are new rows with current rows we cast the data source as above then check for new rows along with validation as needed.

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    If row.RowState = DataRowState.Added Then
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Field(Of String)("CompanyName")) Then
```

Other options, utilize a DataAdapter or setup data via data wizards in the ide where a BindingNavigator is setup with a save button.

If it's important to get the new primary key back the method for all methods can do this too.

The following code sample is from [this MSDN code sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Adding-new-records-into-53ce3eb1) that shows how to get a new key back using OleDb connection and command.

```
Public Function AddNewRow(ByVal CompanyName As String, ByVal ContactName As String, ByVal ContactTitle As String, ByRef Identfier As Integer) As Boolean 
    Dim Success As Boolean = True 


Try 
    Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(Builder.ConnectionString) 
        Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("", cn) 

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customer (CompanyName,ContactName,ContactTitle) Values (@CompanyName,@ContactName,@ContactTitle)" 

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", CompanyName.Trim) 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactName", ContactName.Trim) 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactTitle", ContactTitle.Trim) 

            cn.Open() 

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 

            cmd.CommandText = "Select @@Identity" 
            Identfier = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar) 

        End Using 
    End Using 

Catch ex As Exception 
    Success = False 
End Try 

Return Success 


End Function
```

Comment: i dont understand the part of  row.fields(to integer). It an error to me says Fields is not an member of system.data.datarow

Comment: You need to be targeting Framework 3.5 or higher for Field(Of T) as per MSDN documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396